# Opening graphic application on usb plug

Tags: networking, kubuntu, udev

I'm using Kubuntu 18.04 and Yubikey for VPN authorization.
I want to open Konsole application on key plug-in running `nmcli connection up my_connection` to show me password prompt. I set up udev to run my shell script, but it only blinks the window. It disappears less than in a second.

My /lib/udev/yubikey file is:

```
#!/bin/bash
export DISPLAY=:0
sudo -u user konsole -e "nmcli connection up my_connection"
sudo -u user nmcli connection up my_connection
```

If I run "nmcli connection up my_connection" from opened terminal it works! It works event if I run it using sudo. But not from udev.

Upd.
Added `--hold` key to `konsole` call. Now window stays and I can see: `Error: Connection activation failed: Not authorized to control networking`. Tried adding `sudo -u user nmcli general permissions > /perm.txt` to script. Got this:

```
PERMISSION                                            VALUE
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-network no
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! what happens if you use the `--hold` or `--noclose` option rather than the `-e` as discussed [here?](https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/applications/konsole/command-line-options.html)

Comment: Added. Now window stays and I can see:
`Error: Connection activation failed: Not authorized to control networking.`
Tried adding `sudo -u user nmcli general permissions > /perm.txt` to script. Got this:
`PERMISSION                                                        VALUE 
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-network             no    
`

Comment: Please [edit] the information into your post as comments can get deleted here for numerous reasons. Thank you for helping us help you!